# How to do jquery autocomplete function from a php variable array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, arrays

I want to do an autocomplete text box function, I have a php variable array say `$vararray[]`. it holds these values,
apple, bat, ball, bed, cat, dog, elephant, fox.
Now I want to make a textbox which is enabled with autocomplete textview.
when I click on that textbox, I need to populate first 4 values in that array.
now as i type in letters the suggestions in the textbox should appear relating to what I type in that textbox
like,

for `b--> bat,ball,bed`

for `ba->bat,ball`

I don't want to search in database. all the values are readily available in php array variable

is there any method to do that in jquery or ajax or in any other way?

Comment: take a look at http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: @Pranav C Balan i referd that first, is there any way to assign my $vararray[] values to var availabletags? i mean to make this happen availabletags = $vararray[]?

Comment: i did an autocompele for the same from the database using ajax. and it is working good. but this time i dont want to query database. so i dont know how to start

Comment: okies that's fine but if you would have looked properly at the link which @PranavCBalan shared you would have understood that you don't need to assign values to `availableTags` array instead you just need to just provide source like this `source: YourArrayHere`.

Comment: like this? source : <?php echo  $vararray[] ?>

Answer (score 1):

This is [<kbd>Simple Example</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/DLLVw/) of jquery auto complete.

you just have to pass your `php` array to `jquery` array. like following:

```
<?php 
$arr = array(
0=>array(
"id"=> "1",
        "value"=> "Afghanistan",
        "label"=> "Afghanistan"
),
1=>array(
 "id"=> "17",
        "value"=> "Albania",
        "label"=> "Albania"
));
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var jsArray = <? echo json_encode($arr); ?>;
</script>
```